# Tracking pixels (form plugin + jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, tracking

I was wondering whether what I am doing with our website is the good way to go. We have several different tracking pixels with several different providers. Some of these pixels only have to appear after a form has been submitted through ajax (to register a conversion).

The way I have is setup now is like this :

```
ajaxForm(function(){
  $(".thanks").slideDown(200);
  $("body").append('<img src="TRACKING PIXEL SOURCE" width="1" height="1"/>').append('ANOTHER PIXEL');
});
```

I am using the form plugin.
Is my setup efficient? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: sounds like ancient technology to me. Why don't you just track your users with AJAX and server side scripts?

Comment: Companies we work with, corporate politics... :/

Comment: Seems like a viable way to do it... You insert the images on submit... Cant see how you could do it smarter :D

Answer (score 0):

Doing it  this way removes the redundant stuff, but the outcome is the same:

```
var appendTo = $("body");
$.each(["tracking-pixel-source-1","tracking-pixel-source-2"],function(i,src) {
    $("<img/>", { "width":"1px", "height": "1px", "src": src }).appendTo(appendTo);
});
```